# How to resolve validation.required app Scan issue in java

Tags: java

I run appScan on my application. I got some issues but most of the issues are related to validation.required while setting an attribute to session object in Spring

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: in the spring controller class we are getting CheckDataDTO object from session object 
CheckDataDTO checkDataDTO = (CheckDataDTO) request.getSession().getAttribute(checkDataDTO);
//we will add some changes to checkDataDTO and again we are setting to session object
request.getSession().setAttribute("checkData", checkDataDTO);//here we are getting validation.required issue

Comment: Hello Abdelhak can u please help me in this regard?

Comment: request.getSession().setAttribute("checkData", checkDataDTO);//here we are getting validation.required issue

Comment: try to explain more i can't follow you

Comment: He wanted to say, He was getting validation.required Appscan issue on the below code (similar)
<%
String checkDataDTO = "example";
pageContext.setAttribute("checkData", checkDataDTO);
%>

I'm also facing the same issue.